# Passing a pointer as a shorter array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Will this code give a Buffer overflow crash?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void show(char text[2]) {

  printf("%c%c\n", text[0], text[1]);

  return;
}

int main() {
  char *txt = "aabc";

  show (txt);

  return 0;
}
```

I mean `txt` has 4 characters (plus `'\0'`), while text has only 2.

Comment: Do you expect it to? Why or why not? What is the relationship between arrays and pointers to the same?

Comment: This code should not "crash" as there is nothing wrong with it memory-wise. `char text[2]` will decay to `char *text` anyway.

Comment: Also, you're not going beyond the end of `text[2]`, let alone the original `txt`

Comment: @EugeneSh. But `char a = 'a'; show(&a)` would compile cleanly as `&a` is also a `char *`, and that would invoke UB and possibly crash.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Right. And many other codes will invoke UB as well, but we are talking about this particular one, no?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, the idea is that I have an X-length characters array, and I pass it to a (X - Y) array [Y > 0].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays are passed in C by reference, this means when a function accepts an array as an argument it does not get a copy of that array, but rather a pointer to it.

So in your case `char text[2]` is not a new copy of `txt` in main, but rather a pointer to it. Thus you will not get an overflow as you are not trying to copy the contents of `txt` into `char text[2]`, `text` just points to it.

For example the output of the following is `13`

```
void test(char a[2]){
    printf("%d", strlen(a)); 
}

int main(){
    char* text = "Hello World!\n"; 
    test(text); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken.

The compiler implicitly adjusts a parameter declared like an array to pointer to the array element type.

So this declaration

```
void show(char text[2]);
```

is equivalent to the declaration

```
void show(char *text );
```

You could even declare the function like

```
void show(char text[1000]);
```

In any case the compiler will adjust it to the declaration

```
void show(char *text );
```

That is the function deals with a pointer to the first element of the array passed to the function as an argument or with the value of the passed pointer as an argument.

So neither overflow occurs. The string literal itself is not moved from one part of memory to another. It is the value of the pointer that is passed to the function.

It is your responsibility not to access the passed string beyond the allocated memory for it.

Comment: The OP is not mistaken, as they ask a question, not make an assertion about the behavior.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli If you want to have such a declaration when you have to specify the parameter like  void show(char ( *text )[2]);

Comment: @VladfromMoscow heh, fair enough.

Comment: Why do you start off your answer with an assertion that the OP is mistaken?

Comment: @ryyker He is mistaken about the memory overflow thinking that the function allocates less memory for the passed string literal.

Comment: He asks that question, yes, but makes no assertion.  With respect you should remove that first statement in your answer, it is confusing.  i.e. there is a subtle difference in English between saying _you are mistaken_ and something like: _It would be a wrong assumption to think an overflow will occur._

Comment: @ryyker No the first statement is not confusing. It is his assumption that is wrong and I pointed this in the first statement.